# Why is Apache2 named sometimes apache2 sometimes httpd?

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd

It looks like on Ubuntu and Windows, it's *apache2* but on CentOS, it's *httpd*.

This naming scheme affects the service name, the config directory and filenames,...

Why 2 different names for the same software?

Comment: My guess is that `httpd` is part [heritage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NCSA_HTTPd) and part generic software naming (it doesn't get much more generic that *HTTP Daemon*). You probably also have `sshd` and `ssh`, instead of explicitly named `openssh` on your system.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPd was the Apache Software Foundation's flagship product before it even *was* a foundation. As such, it has been grandfathered into the name "Apache", even though technically it's only the HTTPd project.

Comment: Thanks. But why do different people/distro still use different names? It's the same version of the software after all. Or is it not? Do the people in Ubuntu et al modify the source to compile it as _apache_ rather than _httpd_ ? Or are these 2 different software? TIA

Comment: Because changing it would require a non-trivial amount of work. Hence the grandfathering.